# How to run automate cljs tests in cider?

Tags: testing, clojure, clojurescript

When I run tests in my core_test.clj file in cider, the tests run with no problem whenever I load a buffer, since I have set (cider-auto-test-mode 1). But this doesn't work with the cljs file. I have the following code in core_test.cljs

```
(ns myapp.core-test
  (:require
   [cljs.test         :refer-macros [is deftest]]))

(deftest my-test
  (testing "Arithmetic"
    (testing "with positive integers"
      (is (= 4 (+ 2 2)))
      (is (= 7 (+ 3 4))))
    (testing "with negative integers"
      (is (= -4 (+ -2 -2)))
      (is (= -1 (+ 3 -4))))))
```

And upon doing C-k in core.cljs. The test doesn't run. Why is this and how can I make cljs tests automatic too, just like clj tests?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me it's not supported yet. From the [CIDER docs for ClojureScript](https://docs.cider.mx/cider/cljs/overview.html):

> CIDER works well with ClojureScript, but not all CIDER features are available in ClojureScript (yet). For instance, the test runner and debugger are currently Clojure-only features.

There are other options for running CLJS tests automatically in the command line, for instance, using [Figwheel](https://figwheel.org/docs/testing.html#auto-testing), [Shadow CLJS](https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#target-browser-test) or a [cljs-test-runner](https://github.com/Olical/cljs-test-runner).